# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 6295552 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Crawler\temperatura.php on line 11

Tags: php

```
<?php

require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
class temperatura {
  public function __construct(){
        $this->getTemperatura('https://www.tempoagora.com.br/previsao-do-tempo/pe/Petrolina/');
  }
  public function getTemperatura($url){
        $html = file_get_html($url);
        echo'<pre>';
        print_r($html);

  }
}

$t = new Temperatura();
?>
```

Como permitir que o PHP retorne sem este problema de memória?

Comment: já fez alteração no php.ini?

Comment: Já sim, Nas linhas do endereço: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
 memory_limit=128M para 256M
;opcache.memory_consumption=128 para 512

Comment: Acho que você deveria pensar em usar a API do clima tempo para fazer isso. Porém, faça um teste: Ao invés de usar `print_r($html);` use `echo $html->plaintext;` e veja se o erro continua.

Comment: O Erro não continuou, obtive o seguinte retorno:
"Previsão do tempo para Petrolina - PE - Tempo Agora Clique sobre um dia para ver a previsão por períodoPrevisões por horaTemp.Chuvas"
No caso eu esperava o retorno de um array, mas tudo bem, erro resolvido. Obrigado.

Comment: Ah ta... calma ae que vou criar uma resposta.

Comment: Eu ia criar uma resposta... Mas acho que não é conveniente. Vou mostrar aqui mesmo:

Comment: Segundo a documentação, para você pegar o array do objeto, use: `$html->getAllAttributes ()`; http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm

Comment: É interessante enviar uma resposta para fechar o post

Comment: Vou formular, calma ae...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro aconteceu quando você tentou printar na tela o objeto criado. Essa função [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.print-r.php) do php utiliza buffer de saída e provavelmente recursividade, o que aumenta ainda mais o consumo de memória.

> Esta função usa o interno buffer de saída com este parâmetro, então
>   assim não pode ser usado dentro de uma função de callback para
>   ob_start().

Por isso que quando você utilizou o atributo do objeto `$html->plaintext;` não gerou estouro de memória, pois já estava armazenado lá.

**No caso eu esperava o retorno de um array** (comentário do AP)

Segundo a [documentação](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm), para você pegar o array dos atributos do objeto basta usar esta função:

```
$html->getAllAttributes ();
```